# Solaris 10 : command to copy text to the clipboard. (command line)

Tags: shell-script, solaris

I'm searching a command to copy text to the clipboard.

`xclip` and `xsel` are commands which are available on several Linux and Unix OS-es, but is unfortenuately not available on solaris 10.

http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/x/general/xwin12-Xclipboard/single/

`clipboard` of openSolaris is also not available on solaris 10.
http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1t/clipboard/

Is there a command in Solaris 10 for this issue?
Or is there a way to find the command, which is acitvated when 'copy' on the keyboard is activated?
(`/usr/openwin/demo/xev`)

Comment: Why don't you install xclip or xsel? They may not be installed by default, but they are definitely available.

Comment: @Gilles thanks, because I'm not allowed. 

And the second reason I tried `xclip` on a test machine but I didn't succeed. But for myself I would like to know how I can do it ... `xsel` or `xclip` (prefer the last one `xclip`).
Could you give me more info? (link/tutorial)

I also found it strange that I didn't found a tutorial about `clipboard` of OpenSolaris (since 9) to install it on OS Solaris 10 ...

Comment: I doubt that you would find a tutorial specifically about installing or building xclip. Look for generic tutorials about installing software. Or look for it in one of the Solaris package distributions. First check if it's [provided by Oracle](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=1400676.1) (I can't do that for you because that page stupidly requires an account). If not, try [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) or [Sunfreeware](https://www.sunfreeware.com/introduction.html).

Comment: The clipboard man page you link to for OpenSolaris is not for a command, but is for a Tcl/Tk function you can use when writing Tcl/Tk programs.   As for the Copy key, it doesn't run a separate program, but is treated by the running application as a keyboard shortcut for its builtin copy functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can build `xclip` from source - just as easy as using `pkg`. First step is to download the [tar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/files/latest/download) from `SourceForge`. Then assuming you have `GCC` installed, all you need to do is the following:

```
tar xvf xclip-0.12.tar.gz
cd xclip-0.12
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This will install `xclip` to `/usr/local/bin` so make sure you have that in your `PATH` environment variable. Works like a charm for me on `Solaris 11.2` - should not be any different on `Solaris 10`.